# How to remove attribute entirely from child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to remove the attribute "data-processed" from a child div of a component. I cant just set it to null or false, it needs to be removed.

In classic JS, I'd need something like:

```js
$('#mermaid').html(node.data.graph).removeAttr('data-processed');
```

But that will not seem to work here. I have used useRef to specify the ref to the div, but I cannot find any documentation on how to remove the attribute from the element at the ref. Is this at all possible to do in react?

Comment: As a addendum, the attribute is created by react mermaid and therefore I cannot control the method in which it is created

Comment: (The accepted answer correctly answers this question, but if you're having the same problem I did you need to put a key on the div container above and iterate it once each time to reset it, thats what worked for me)

Comment: Would it be possible to share a full code snippet for how this has worked for you? I am running into this exact same problem (trying to re-render a mermaid diagram without reloading the entire page/deleting the div), but even with adding a key to my div I am not seeing the graph re-render when I make changes to it. Are you using a const function to update the graph whenever a change is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vanilla **removeAttribute** method on the DOM node using useRef. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute

```
const domRef = useRef();

domRef.current.removeAttribute('data-processed');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

1. Using **[removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)** method on element:

```js
document.getElementById('mermaid').removeAttribute('data-processed')
```

2. Using ref (which is better):

```js
elementRef.current.removeAttribute('data-processed');
```